# How to insert html form using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I understand this is wrong, probably with inserting the divs, but not sure where to go from here:

```
$('#memberForm').html('<form class="msform" method="POST"><fieldset><h2 class="fs-title">Create your account</h2><div class="full-col"><input placeholder="Email" type="email" /><input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" /><input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="password_again" /></div><input type="button" name="Submit" value="Submit" /></fieldset></form>');
```

Comment: use append() function look here http://jsfiddle.net/APA2S/1933/

Comment: @user3127896 There's also nothing wrong with `.html()` depending on your needs.

Comment: That is JQuery, not Javascript. So in order to get this to work you would need to import the JQuery library

Comment: Nothing is wrong with that. What do you *think* is wrong?

Comment: So what are you expecting, and what are you getting, and what is the problem ?

Comment: Thanks - what I'm trying to do is use google experiments to show two different form to customers, however, neither shows up when I use this method. I haven't had trouble using js or jquery with these experiments before

Comment: Seems to work fine on its own http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gQxCr/. Although there's no submit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with what you have there, as long as what you are intending to do is set the inner HTML to be a static chunk of HTML.

Beware though that if you start setting dynamic properties (such as inner text of elements, attributes, etc.) then do not concatenate that data into the HTML.  You must set using `.attr()` and similar, otherwise you risk creating invalid HTML and open yourself to injection attacks.